# how can we send input value to directives

Tags: angular

I want to pass input field value dynamically to directives. I have to send that input value to server via post request in directive. How can i do this???

*my html code*

```
     <input type="text" [appHighlight]="appHighlight">
```

*my directive code*

```
     import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2, HostBinding, TemplateRef, 
     ViewContainerRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
     import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
     import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
     import { HelloService } from './hello.service';

     @Directive({
     selector: '[appHighlight]',

     })
    export class HighlightDirective {
    @Input('appHighlight') appHighlight: string;
     constructor(private el: ElementRef, private http: HttpClient, private hello: 
     HelloService ) { }


    @HostListener('keyup.enter') disableInput(val) {
     console.log(val)
    this.hello.postauthorized({"key":this.appHighlight}).subscribe((res)=>{
     console.log(res)
     })

     }
   ngOnInit(){
  console.log(this.appHighlight)
   }

   }
```

Comment: ngOnChange - SimpleChanges

Comment: this.el.nativeElement.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of the input by injecting its ElementRef into the directive :

HTML

```html
<input type="text" appHighlight>
```

TS

```javascript
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  constructor(private elmt: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>) {}

  @HostListener('keyup.enter') validate() {
    const value = this.elmt.nativeElement.value;
    /* Do anything you want with this value */
  }
}
```

Hop it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <input type="text" #input appHighlight [appHighlight]="input.value">
```